# Spring Boot: property spring.jpa.show-sql doesn't work with Datastore

Tags: spring-boot, google-cloud-datastore

I have an application that works with Google Datastore. In order to work with database I use JPA. The repository implements `DatastoreRepository` from `org.springframework.cloud.gcp.data.datastore.repository`.

I want to see all queries that application makes to database so I set `spring.jpa.show-sql` to `true` but it doesn't work for me.

Does anybody have same issue? How can it be fixed?

**EDIT**

Dependencies in project:

```
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-gcp-starter-data-datastore:1.1.1.RELEASE'
compileOnly 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
annotationProcessor 'org.projectlombok:lombok'
testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
```

Thanks

Comment: how does your pom.xml look like? Which dependencies do you use?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli i've edited the question with more details

Comment: spring.jpa.show-sql will not help because you are not using JPA. You have to check the GCP documentation to see how to log the data access

Comment: @SimonMartinelli thanks, I'll check the documentation and come back

Comment: It seems they do not have this feature

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try to add a datasource proxy:

There is the documentation: https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy

And here is a example with Spring Boot:

https://github.com/ttddyy/datasource-proxy-examples/blob/master/springboot-autoconfig-example/README.md